# An Invalid Parameter was entered:

Tags: paypal

I send the normal login stuff I used yesterday, and worked fine, now today I get the above error. No information is being returned on what the error might be.

I am using the sandbox mode for paypal?

Any idea why this is happening?

Data Passed:

payment Object:

paymentType: 1
customID: anythingYouWant
memo: Registration of your Garage Sale
tax: 0
recipient: seller@iinet.net.au
ipnUrl: http://wp.g-saler.com/
merchantName: GSaler Sale
currency: AUD
subtotal: 3
shipping: 0
invoiceItems: [object Object]

invoice object:

name: Garage Sale
itemCount: 1
totalPrice: 3
itemPrice: 3

API: MEP

Comment: What API call are you trying to make?  Can you provide the API request that you are sending over so that we can see what you are trying to pass and so that we can try to reproduce the issue to see what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly started receiving this error message from the payment service:

```
The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments
```

I suggest creating a business sandbox account located in US.

Comment: Not all countries support the option of being able to receive payments.  Some countries can only use PayPal to make a purchase, not to receive funds.

Comment: What is the country that your account is set up under?

Comment: There should not be an issue with this country.  Can you provide the request you are sending, and the full response that you are getting back?